# Exception has occurred: Trace/breakpoint trap - Debugging a C++ program in VSCode (uses dynamic memory allocation)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using Dynamic memory allocation in this code for deleting for nodes. Upon encountering a `delete someVar` I am getting an error in the VSCode debugger.

```
Exception has occurred
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

I do not understand what is the meaning of **Trace/breakpoint trap**. Could you explain it? Also, kindly help me detect what is wrong with my code?
(BTW this is me setting up a solution for leetcode, kindly ignore the lengthy setup of the list in main)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::map;


/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */


class ListNode {
public:
    ListNode *next;
    int val;
    ListNode(int arg_val = 0, ListNode* arg_next = nullptr) {
        val = arg_val;
        next = arg_next;
    }
};


class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* arg_head, int arg_n) {
        ListNode* head = arg_head;
        ListNode* traverser = arg_head;
        ListNode* nexter = arg_head->next;
        ListNode* previous = traverser;
        int index = 0;
        bool zero = false;
        map<int, ListNode*> store;
        signed int justcals[] = {arg_n - 0,
                                 arg_n - 5,
                                 arg_n - 10,
                                 arg_n - 15,
                                 arg_n - 20,
                                 arg_n - 25,
                                 arg_n - 30};

        if (arg_n == 1) {
            delete traverser;
            traverser = nullptr;
            return nexter;
        }

        while (traverser->next != nullptr) {
            if (index % 5 == 0) store.insert({index, traverser});
            traverser = traverser->next;
            index = index + 1;
        }
        int min = 99999;
        for (index = 0; index < 7; ++index) {
            if (justcals[index] >= 0 && justcals[index] < min) {
                if (justcals[index] == 0) {
                    zero = true;
                    min = justcals[index - 1] + (5 * (index - 1));
                } else {
                    if (index == 0) min = 0;
                    else min = justcals[index] + (5 * index);
                }
            }
        }
        traverser = store.at(min);
        index = min;
        if (zero) {
            traverser = head;
            index = 0;
        }
        while (index != arg_n - 1) {
            traverser = traverser->next;
            index = index + 1;
        }
        traverser = traverser->next;
        nexter = traverser->next;
        delete traverser;
        previous->next = nexter;
        return head;
    }
};


int main() {
    Solution solver;
    ListNode *lsptr;
    ListNode node1(1);
    ListNode node2(2);
    ListNode node3(3);
    ListNode node4(4);
    ListNode node5(5);
    ListNode node6(6);
    ListNode node7(7);
    lsptr = &node2; node1.next = lsptr;
    lsptr = &node3; node2.next = lsptr;
    lsptr = &node4; node3.next = lsptr;
    lsptr = &node5; node4.next = lsptr;
    lsptr = &node6; node5.next = lsptr;
    lsptr = &node7; node6.next = lsptr;
    lsptr = &node1;
    cout << &*(solver.removeNthFromEnd(lsptr, 3)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're calling delete on a pointer that points to a local stack based variable.

Comment: `lsptr = &node2; node1.next = lsptr;` Convoluted. `node1.next = &node2;` is simpler and probably less confusing.

Comment: thank you for your help everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` should only be used with an object that has been created with `new`.

You create objects on the stack and set `lsptr` to point to them. Note that the list nodes were not created by `new`. You then delete `lsptr`, which is invalid because they were not created by `new`. This causes an exception. The exception is not handled by the program, so it notifies the operating system that the program has failed. This is called trapping into the operating system. The OS then handles the failure by either: stopping the program and jumping to a debugger (if setup), aka breakpoint trap, or kills your program.

To fix the program, remove the deletes. You don't need to delete stack allocations, only heap allocated objects (`new`).